# Process.TotalProcessorTime exceeds the actual time passing

Tags: c#, .net

I want to calculate the average CPU usage % between two points of time.
I use the ratio between t1-t0 and Process.TotalProcessorTime1 - Process.TotalProcessorTime0
(where t is the actual `DateTime.Now` at that point)

but sometimes when the computer is busy I get the TotalProcessorTime difference in Ticks is larger than the actual time (in Ticks) that passed, so my cpu% exceeds 100.

how can that be?

```
long currentLogTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
long currentSPUUsageTime = _process.TotalProcessorTime.Ticks;

long timeDiff= currentLogTime - m_LastLogTime;
if (timeDiff != 0)
{
    cpuUsage = (currentSPUUsageTime - m_LastCPUUsageTime) * 100 / timeDiff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a single process uses more than one processor, it can use processor time in faster than real time.

Comment: Also known as the free lunch!

Comment: so should i divide by the number of processor cores in the machine?

Comment: If you want to calculate the used processor time as a percentage of the maximum possible used processor time, then yes (unless your process is limited to some subset of the machine's logical processors).

Comment: @tsvikaw: It depends on what you want to measure. Bear in mind that things like hyperthreading make life tricky, as well as CPUs which vary their clock speed depending on how many CPUs are actually active, etc.

Comment: is there another short way to get the cpu% when i need to output to my logger?

Comment: @tsvikaw: Not that I'm aware of. Personally I think I'd log the processor time taken rather than a percentage... I think it's a more meaningful number.

Comment: @tsvikaw if you measure time in high-resoluton (see my answer) then your %-usage will be quite accurate. I guess it won't hurt if it sometimes reads more than 100%? I still gives you a good indication on what's going on.

Comment: High resolution wo'nt really help here, because I measure in period of about 1 second and still get much more than 1000ms difference in CPUTime

Comment: Checked and tested on dual core: got 4% when task manager shows 2%. Checked and tested on quad core: got 10% when task manager shows 2-3%

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` is measured with a lower resolution than `TotalProcessorTime`.

You'll need to use a high-resolution timer to measure the elapsed time. Consider using a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instance for this purpose.

Use the [StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx) method when you start a new "log period":

```
        m_stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
```

Then simply read the [ElapsedTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) property to determine how much time that has elapsed:

```
        long timeDiff= m_stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
```